# AutoUpdate/Add some files within the app

Tags: android, c++, ios, c, xcode

We are working on a mobile game right now, I'm wondering how some games has this "Checking for Updates" line in the main loading screen, then if there is an update they automatically update the game from within the game itself (without sending you the the app store).

So we have a server and everything, just need to know how to do that properly so we won't wait 10 days for the iTunes approval if we just want to do a mini-update with some new graphics.

It would be great to learn how to do that on both iOS and Android, but iOS is the aim right now.

Some examples would be: CoC, Heroes Charge etc...

Answer (score 1):

For iOS:

What these games do is getting new DATA for the game, not getting new code. There is no way to install an app (or an app update) without going through the app store (except when jailbreaking your device).

It may be possible to get some new javascript from your server and execute that in your app within a webview, but I doubt that is useful in most cases.

Comment: This is exactly what I meant, please read the question before answering. _"do a mini-update with some new graphics"_. I never wanted to update the code itself.

Comment: Well, then it's a yes. The first part of your question sounded like you were looking for a way to update your game code, too - my apologies for misunderstanding. As for "learning how to do it": it's just data, so you only have to contact your server API (probably with some app hash code to ensure it's your app making the call) with the update state of your app, and retrieve the data necessary according to that update state.